# Helper or Class Method for this use case - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5.

Goal: When users sign up, they are required to enter their full name (this is one column in the DB). In various parts of my app (mostly views), I would like to split their name up to just display their first name.

Ways I can go about it:

1 - helper method

```
# application_helper.rb

def first_name(full_name)
  full_name.split[0]
end
```

2 - class method

```
 # user.rb

 def first_name
   self.full_name.split[0]
 end
```

Which way is the preferred way to do this? Are there advantages/disadvantages to either? I am having a hard time figuring out which one to use, or if it's just preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things. First, this:

```
# user.rb

def first_name
  self.full_name.split[0]
end
```

is not a class method. It's an instance method.

Second, IMO, you want as *little* logic in your views as possible. And, your views shouldn't know *anything* about your models or their internal workings. What happens if, for some reason, your model or your data changes and `full_name.split[0]` is no longer the way to get at the first name? Then, you'll have to remember that you put that logic in a helper and go change it there.

So, go with choice #2 - the instance method.